# I dont see html part in template plugin of ckeditor 4

Tags: ckeditor

I am not able to see html part of template plugin of ckeditor when I clicked on source button
My code is:

CKEDITOR.addTemplates('default', {
    imagesPath: CKEDITOR.getUrl(CKEDITOR.plugins.getPath('templates') + 'templates/images/'),
    templates: [{
        title: 'my.XHTML',
        image: 'te.gif',
        description: 'Df template.',
        html: ' '
    },
    ]
});

so now if I select my template then click on source then it should show html part i.e

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"xmlns:h="http//schema.my.org/UI">
```

but now its only show

```
    <html>
```

please help me in this? whats wrong I am doing?

Comment: please anyone help me since I am new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve above issue just update your config.js file with following code

config.allowedContent = true;

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: This prob is solved but its work properly in chrome and firefox but not in IE.
please help me .